# Can some please help me and show me what I'm doing wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE DateRange
([Date] DATETIME, IsFutureOrPast BIT)

    DECLARE @Date AS DATETIME
    SET @DATE ='2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    WHILE @DATE <='2014-12-31 00:00:00.000'
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO DateRange ([DATE])
            VALUES (@DATE)
            SET @Date = @Date + 1
        END

--Case Statement to check values and enter flag
    DECLARE @CurrentDate AS DATETIME = GETDATE()
        UPDATE 
            DateRange
        SET  [DATE] =
             CASE
                WHEN @CurrentDate <= [DATE] THEN 0
                ELSE 1
                END AS IsPastOrFuture
                FROM DateRange
                WHERE [Date] IN ( 0, 1)
```

Comment: What is the Error? Also your statement `SET [DATE] = CASE WHEN @CurrentDate <= [DATE] THEN 0 ELSE 1 END` doesn't make sense unless `DATE` is a BIT column.

Comment: Your table def says `DATE` is a DATETIME column. I think you mixed up the data types of your column.

Comment: First make your title specific to your problem, not just "_help me please_" and secondly add some details to your question rather than just dumping your code without any explanation about what is wrong with it and what errors you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DateRange TABLE
([Date] DATETIME, IsFutureOrPast BIT)

    DECLARE @Date AS DATETIME
    SET @DATE ='2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    WHILE @DATE <='2014-12-31 00:00:00.000'
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @DateRange ([DATE])
            VALUES (@DATE)
            SET @Date = @Date + 1
        END

--Case Statement to check values and enter flag
    DECLARE @CurrentDate AS DATETIME = GETDATE()
        UPDATE 
            @DateRange
        SET  IsFutureOrPast =
             CASE
                WHEN @CurrentDate <= [DATE] THEN 0
                ELSE 1
                END 
                FROM @DateRange


SELECT * FROM @DateRange
```

Comment: Thank you Jiggs, that does exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set the `DATE` field when you should be setting the `IsFutureOrPast` field:

```
    UPDATE 
        DateRange
    SET  [IsFutureOrPast] =
            CASE WHEN @CurrentDate <= [DATE] THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END
```

But you could also combine the two statements:

```
        INSERT INTO DateRange ([DATE], [IsFutureOrPast])
        VALUES (
            @DATE, 
            CASE WHEN GETDATE() <= @DATE THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  
        )
        SET @Date = @Date + 1
```

Comment: Also `IsFutureOrPast` and `IsPastOrFuture` are both referenced... unless I'm missing some magic of sql server, that's probably a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to `SET` the `IsPastOrFuture` column

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate AS DATETIME = GETDATE()
    UPDATE 
        DateRange
    SET 
        IsPastOrFuture = CASE
                             WHEN @CurrentDate <= [DATE] THEN 0
                             ELSE 1
                         END
```